# HOw can i read 950MB txt File in C#

Tags: c#, file, text-files

I need to read a 950mb txt file in a console app without getting a `System.OutOfMemoryException`,  with the following structure:

```
"6152902100000017";20110701;20110701;53;"D";30359130;"NOTA DE DEBITO";"DEB.COMPRA BCO";0;;0;"6152902100000017";0;0;0;0;0;"902"
```

I can read smaller files but the exception is thrown on bigger files.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't actually need the WHOLE thing in memory all at once do you?  You should probably process it in sections

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the file ? are you accessing it one line at a time ? or do you need the wohle in-memory at once ? please show some source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will almost always fail, 950MB at 2 Bytes/char is too close to the 2GB limit :

```
string AllText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

Reading it as an array of string will probably work (esp on a 64 bit system) if you have 4+ GB:

```
string[] AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

But your best bet is to process it 1 line at a time:

```
// requires Fx4
foreach(string line in File.GetLines(fileName))
{
    // use 'line'
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, which one?

Answer (score 5):

Don't read the entire file into a buffer.  Only read as many bytes at a time as you need.

Answer (score 3):

If your using StreamReader use ReadLine() or ReadBlock() to grab a section of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StreamReader` for this case and read one line at a time from the source rather than putting entire file into a buffer.